# What's the difference between a crater and a vent?

Tags: geology

Crater is above a vent
whereas a vent is below it.
All the best....

Comment: please give some information and upload a picture or give us .a link to make it clear what you realy are asking.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because homework questions are expected to show some attempt to answer them.

Answer (score 4):

A vent opens through the side of a volcano, somewhere on its slopes. The crater (and neck) can seal itself up, solidify over a period of inactivity, then re-open anew nearby to form a new crater. Magma will more readily move through the interface between a solidified neck and surrounding ash matrix than it will through the center of a solidified neck alone.

[image: Multiple craters atop Olympus Mons]

Answer (score 3):

A crater is what you can see on the top of a volcano and the vent is the tube leading to the crater. Sometimes fissures on the volcano can make a secondary volcanic cone if a volcano is a long periodic one which allows the magma to go sideways where the resistance might be lower.
https://golearngeo.wordpress.com/2010/02/24/volcano-features/